# Address Sanitizer : heap use after free crash when iterating through map of shared_ptr and coming out of scope

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a map containing shared_ptr as values.In the function deleteB, I iterate through the map looking for a particular key value, when found, I erase the particular key, value pair and break out of the for loop, but as soon I come out of the deleteB function, the program crashes.I used address sanitizer and it shows `heap use after free error`.Not sure, where exactly this crash is happening.

```
struct MyObj{
  int val;
  void* ctx;
};

class A{
  private:
    MyObj obj;
    int countVal;
  public:
  A(int value){
     countVal = value;
     obj = (MyObj){countVal, this};
  }
  ~A(){}
   MyObj getObj(){
     return obj;
   }
};

class B{
  private:
  int count = 0;
  map<uint32_t, shared_ptr<A>> mB;

  public:
   void createB(MyObj &obj, int &getCount){ 
    ++count;
    mB[count] = make_shared<A>(count);
    obj = mB[count]->getObj();
    getCount = count;
   }

   void deleteB(int Val){
       if(!mB.empty()){
         for(auto &a : mB){
           if(a.first == Val){
              mB.erase(a.first);
              break;
           }
         }
       }
   }
};


int main(){
  B b;
  MyObj objVal;
  int count = 0;
  b.createB(objVal, count);
  b.deleteB(count);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `~A()` do?

Comment: It is A’s destructor function call.

Comment: That's not a destructor call. It's a declaration.

Comment: I mean, what actions does destructor of `A` perform? What is its definition? You have a declaration, so it must have a definition somewhere.

Comment: It’s not doing anything, other than being a default destructor

Comment: What flags do you use to compile your program? I cannot reproduce your crash using `clang++` with `-fsanitize=address`.

Comment: `~A(){}` --> `~A() = default;` - that's better since you then have a trivial destructor.  Won't solve your problem though. Just wanted to point out that a user defined destructor (even when empty) is *not* the same as a default destructor.

Comment: Address sanitizer should give you a stack trace as to where the deletion is happening.

Comment: I am using address sanitizer flag in Android.mk, and I can see the backtrace but it is pointing to addresses in the executable, not sure how to translate the address to track down the exact line that is causing the crash.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the crash with an Android 8.1 r52 toolchain. Please specify the Android version you are using and whether your Android.mk creates a host or target binary. Also, you could try to improive the stack trace readability by adding `-g` to your `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS`.

Comment: It’s Android R, will try to add -g, no sure how to use llvm-symboliser, because it’s entire Android R build.